# Is this C++ code exception safe?

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following code from [mysql.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html):

```
/* Copyright 2008, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
the Free Software Foundation; version 2 of the License.

There are special exceptions to the terms and conditions of the GPL
as it is applied to this software. View the full text of the
exception in file EXCEPTIONS-CONNECTOR-C++ in the directory of this
software distribution.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
GNU General Public License for more details.

You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301 USA
*/

/* Standard C++ includes */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different
  headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/
#include "mysql_connection.h"

#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
cout << endl;
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'..." << endl;

try {
  sql::Driver *driver;
  sql::Connection *con;
  sql::Statement *stmt;
  sql::ResultSet *res;

  /* Create a connection */
  driver = get_driver_instance();
  con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
  /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
  con->setSchema("test");

  stmt = con->createStatement();
  res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
  while (res->next()) {
    cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
    /* Access column data by alias or column name */
    cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
    cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
    /* Access column data by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
    cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
  }
  delete res;
  delete stmt;
  delete con;

} catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
  cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
  cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
  cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
  cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}

cout << endl;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I always thought that a code like that is not exception safe because the `delete` statements are not executed in case of an exception and hence `unique_ptr` or some other kind of smart pointers should be used. But since this is an official code sample, I am not sure about this. So:

Is the above code sample exception safe?

Comment: No, you are completely correct. Regarding of memory leaks, it isn't exception safe.

Comment: There's a lot of bad code out there, even from official sources.

Comment: Why not use smart pointers?

Comment: I'm starting to doubt, if we should go for MySQL as our production database.

Comment: The code is ugly, but will not cause any issues that could be fixed by smart pointers. What makes you think it isn't exception-save? Which of the two guarantees would you like? Also, btw, your question is off-topic because the code is far from a minimal example as required by the site rules.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Depends on how you define _exception safety_.

Comment: Code samples like this are usually intended just to demonstrate a specific principle. They often leave out other details like error checking because they'll clutter the code and make it hard to understand. They should not be considered examples of proper coding in general.

Comment: @TheDude, since any exception there is followed by program termination, any resources allocated will be released anyway. I'd suggest improving the code by just removing the `catch` part. If there's an exception, just let it fly and avoid `return EXIT_SUCCESS` on the way.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt After giving all that a closer look, I believe MySQL is still in my boat then. ;-)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I'd love to have a static code analysis tool at hand, which detects such copied example code and _"black ducks"_ it to the CI system.

Comment: Check the exceptions guarantee levels :) You will understand more then!!!

Comment: @AlexTheo Exception _guarantees_ guarantee exceptions or not, so what?

Comment: @TheDude this code doesn't provide even a basic exception guarantee
Just read through
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_safety

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is the above code sample exception safe?

#### H**l no!

It's exactly like you're saying. The code you show leaks like a sieve upon exceptions.

RAII or `std::unique` pointers should be used.

Even for pre-standard c++ code, there was the good ole `std::auto_ptr`.

---

> But since this is an official code sample, I am not sure about this.

Well, Open Source doesn't necessarily mean it's anything *"official"*, or anyhow *"better"* than closed source code, where the developers are hidden from the customer's eyes.

That's all.

---

#### Well, to be fair (with the MySQL contributors):

It is a minimal usage example, and any memory leaks would be cleaned up when the `main()` function block exits and the process dies.

But not really a *gem* of a good example. Given the fact that many mediocre programmers are out there, and make up their living with *"CTRL-C CTRL-V codez from teh samplez and tuz"* I'm not so sure that's a good strategy.

---

#### Conclusio:

Don't blindly copy and take over example code, even not that one from the *official documentation* pages of a library, tool, or from a book verbatim.

These are meant to be simplified, and may focus on the usage of the library features with least distraction of the reader.

They're fairly **leaving you being in charge** to use their stuff correctly.

---

#### What I would do to fix it:

I'd consider to provide a thin wrapping layer based on owned and shared pointers as simple class members (see [Dynamic memory management](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory)) and lambda functions:

```
class MySQLQuery;

class MySQLConnection {
    std::function<void(void*)> driverCleanup_;
    std::function<void>(void*) connectionCleanup_;
    std::unique_ptr<sql::Driver> driver_;
    std::shared_ptr<sql::Connection> con_;
public:
    MySQLConnection
        ( const std::string& ipAddress
        , const std::string& user
        , const std::string& password
        ) : 
        driverCleanup_([](void *driver) {
          // (sql::Driver*)driver->cleanup(); ## Whatever necessary
          delete driver;
        }) ,
        connectionCleanup_([](void *connection) {
          // (sql::Connection*)connection->cleanup();
          delete connection;
        }),
        driver_(get_driver_instance(),driverCleanup_),
        con_(std::make_shared(driver_->connect(ipAddress,user,password)
                             ,connectionCleanup_))
    {}

    std::unique_ptr<MySQLQuery> CreateQuery(const std::string& query);
};
```

---

```
class MySQLQuery {
     friend class MySQLConnection;

     std::shared_ptr<sql::Connection> con_;
     std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement stmt_;
     MySQLQuery
       ( std::shared_ptr<sql::Connection> connection
       , const std::string& query
       ) : con_(connection) 
         , stmt_(con_->createStatement()
     {
     }
public:
     // And so on ...
     MySQLResultSet Execute() {
        return stmt_->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
     }
};
```

---

```
std::unique_ptr<MySQLQuery> MySQLConnection::CreateQuery(const std::string& query) 
{
    return std::make_unique<MySQLQuery>(con_,query);
}
```

Also, you might consider to catch any exceptions in the deleter functions code. Though ***never (re-)throw exceptions** from deleters. This screws you up all of a kind.

Being *harnished* in all kind of directions if the cost is low, is always a good idea IMO.